# SQL Transpose rows to columns without aggregate

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I know there is lot of answers but none of my use.
My table looked like

[image]

where we store meter on and off status on given time. After every Off status there is an On status. We want to transpose table like this

```
    MeterNo |       [power off]       |          [power on]
____________________________________________________________________
  x0039938  | 2016-10-08 14:14:37.610 | 2016-10-08 14:17:15.047
____________________________________________________________________
  x0039938  | 2016-10-08 14:20:50.257 | NULL
____________________________________________________________________
  x0039938  | 2016-10-08 14:23:07.610 | 2016-10-08 14:23:17.920
____________________________________________________________________
  x0039940  | 2016-10-08 15:45:38.250 | 2016-10-08 15:52:40.080
____________________________________________________________________
```

and so on

I tried this query

```
    SELECT *
  FROM
(
  SELECT MeterNo, Status, CreatedOn
    FROM [BreakdownShutdowDetails]
) s
PIVOT
(
  MAX(CreatedOn) FOR Status IN ( [power off], [power on])
) p
```

which gives only on result per meterno like this

[image]

Basic idea to get time duration between Off on On status of each meter.
Please suggest for right query.
Thanks.

**Update 1**
Sample data

```
1   x0039938    power off   2016-10-08 14:14:37.610
2   x0039938    power on    2016-10-08 14:17:15.047
3   x0039938    power off   2016-10-08 14:20:50.257
4   x0039938    power off   2016-10-08 14:23:07.610
5   x0039938    power on    2016-10-08 14:23:17.920
6   x0039940    power off   2016-10-08 15:45:38.250
7   x0039940    power on    2016-10-08 15:52:40.080
8   x0040281    power off   2016-10-08 15:59:26.513
9   x0040281    power on    2016-10-08 16:20:23.323
10  x0039940    power off   2016-10-08 16:26:29.133
19  x0040281    power off   2016-10-08 17:17:48.900
22  x0039937    power off   2016-10-08 17:24:24.617
23  x0039937    power on    2016-10-08 17:24:38.590
24  x0039937    power off   2016-10-08 17:33:31.843
25  x0039937    power on    2016-10-08 17:35:47.470
27  x0039940    power off   2016-10-08 17:37:18.360
28  x0040281    power on    2016-10-08 17:40:08.093
30  x0043637    power off   2016-10-09 14:32:23.130
31  x0039937    power off   2016-10-09 14:32:24.893
32  x0040281    power off   2016-10-09 14:32:27.387
33  x0039940    power off   2016-10-09 14:32:29.407
34  x0040281    power on    2016-10-09 15:01:42.480
```

Comment: This looks like a gaps and islands problem.

Comment: What is the version of sql-server?

Comment: @Viki888 SQL Server 2008

Comment: Can you provide sample data in text format instead of image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It called commonly called as [Gaps and islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem. Try something like this (Not tested)

```
SELECT MeterNo,
       [power off] = Min(CASE
                           WHEN status = 'power off' THEN CreatedOn
                         END),
       [power on] = Min(CASE
                           WHEN status = 'power on' THEN CreatedOn
                         END)
FROM   (SELECT *,
                Row_number() OVER (partition BY MeterNo ORDER BY CreatedOn) - 
                Dense_rank() OVER (partition BY MeterNo ORDER BY status)  AS seq_grp
        FROM   Yourtable) t
GROUP  BY MeterNo,
          seq_grp
```

Comment: sample data provided

Comment: @صفي - Did you test it ?