# SQL Island with just one date column and duplicated criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm coming to ask for help, I have been trying to generate the islands for a data set of records but I wasn't able to do it, I have tried with things like Lag functions, generate row over each record, then generate the islands, but not getting the right result.

Reference of solutions that I've tried: [Show Date Range in Custom Column - Gaps and Islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487964/show-date-range-in-custom-column-gaps-and-islands)

I need to generate this data structure:

```
 | ChartShiftWeekdayDetailId | IslandStartsOn | IslandEndsOn | NoLinkingReason |
 |          3600             |   2021-06-25   |   2021-07-01 | 'Can't be .....'|
 |          3600             |   2021-07-02   |   2021-07-14 |       null      |
 |          3600             |   2021-07-15   |   2021-07-31 | 'Can't be .....'|
 |          3600             |   2021-08-01   |   2021-08-05 |       null      |
```

and this is a example of records that should generate the expected result.

[image: ref dataset]

I have achieve this result

[image]

But as you can see this not the expected result.

This is what I've tried:

```sql
SELECT *,
       CONCAT(NoLinkingReason,
              CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY,
                            LAG(DateValue, 1, CAST(ClearedData.DateValue AS datetime) - 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ChartShiftWeekdayDetailId,
                                                                                                              NoLinkingReason
                                                                                                 ORDER BY DateValue),
                            DateValue) AS varchar(10))) AS NumDays
FROM ClearedData;
```

I would really appreciate and thankful all your help.

Comment: So what have you tried, why didn't it work? You reference a different question, and the answer(s) on the question appear to be what you want.

Comment: Hi @Larnu sure, I have tried the usage of the Lag function as the referenced linked, but the result that I'm having is very closed to be the correct one, but if you can see, the first row goes from 2021-06-10 to 2021-07-31, that is not correct since there is another island in the middle that goes from 2021-07-02 to 2021-07-14.

Comment: Use the [edit] feature.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the link and other answers it's apparent the gaps haven't been defined correctly.  This answer uses some data I made up. You could try something like this

```
with 
gaps_cte as (
    select *, case when lag(NoLinkingReason, 1, NoLinkingReason) 
                            over (partition by ChartShiftWeekdayDetailId order by DateValue)<>NoLinkingReason then 1 
                   when lag(NoLinkingReason, 1, NoLinkingReason) 
                            over (partition by ChartShiftWeekdayDetailId order by DateValue) is null and NoLinkingReason is not null then 1
                   when lag(NoLinkingReason, 1, NoLinkingReason) 
                            over (partition by ChartShiftWeekdayDetailId order by DateValue) is not null and NoLinkingReason is null then 1
                   else 0 end gap
    from (values (3600, cast('2021-06-25' as date), 'Something'),
                 (3600, cast('2021-06-26' as date), 'Something'),
                 (3600, cast('2021-06-27' as date), 'Nothing'),
                 (3600, cast('2021-06-28' as date), 'Nothing'),
                 (3600, cast('2021-06-29' as date), null),
                 (3600, cast('2021-06-30' as date), Null),
                 (3600, cast('2021-07-01' as date), 'Something'),
                 (3600, cast('2021-07-02' as date), 'Something')
                  ) v(ChartShiftWeekdayDetailId, DateValue, NoLinkingReason)),
grps_cte as (
    select *, sum(gap) over (partition by ChartShiftWeekdayDetailId order by DateValue) grp
    from gaps_cte)
select ChartShiftWeekdayDetailId, 
       min(DateVAlue) IslandStartsOn,
       max(DateVAlue) IslandEndsOn,
       max(NoLinkingReason) NoLinkingReason
from grps_cte
group by ChartShiftWeekdayDetailId, grp
order by min(DateVAlue);
```

```
ChartShiftWeekdayDetailId   IslandStartsOn  IslandEndsOn    NoLinkingReason
3600                        2021-06-25      2021-06-26      Something
3600                        2021-06-27      2021-06-28      Nothing
3600                        2021-06-29      2021-06-30      NULL
3600                        2021-07-01      2021-07-02      Something
```

Comment: Awesome @SteveC.
I got your sample and implemented it on my query and it works perfectly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have data for every day (as in the example data), you can subtract an enumerated value from the date and get a constant for the specific groups.  The enumeration would be separate for each linking reason:

```
select ChartShiftWeekdayDetailId, NoLinkingReason,
       min(datevalue), max(datevalue)
from (select cd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ChartShiftWeekdayDetailId, NoLinkingReason order by datevalue) as seqnum
      from ClearedData cd
     ) cd
group by datediff(day, -seqnum, datevalue)
```